# ImageView with rouded corners, solid border and glow effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I want to put rounded corners and border to an ImageView, with custom border color. Also, I would like to achieve a glowing effect with the color of the border. Attached sample image. Note that the source image has square borders.
I suppose this is achievable only by using Canvas? Any ideas and sample code?

[image]

Comment: If you have already the background (the image with rounded border) add it as background to the ImageView, then use src to set the imageview's content

Answer (score 1):

this is what i have done for my ImageView to make same changes as you want.

made one image_shape.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke 
        android:width="1dp" 
        />
    <corners 
        android:radius="50dp" />

    <padding 
        android:left="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp"/>


    <solid android:color="#10151D"/>

</shape>
```

Now, put this xml as the background of your imageView then you will get effect as you want.
Right now i have set my own color. you can put your desire color and get effect as rounded glow border effect.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but this is not what I want. This only creates rounded corners but not rounded ImageView, also it doesn't have the glow effect.

Answer (score 0):

try using the following code in a new xml file named roundCorners in your drawable folder:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="#000000" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#DDDDDD" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
    android:topRightRadius="2dp" />

</shape>
```

And then set it as a background to your ImageView in the layout file by:

```
android:background="@drawable/roundCorners"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:thickness="0dp" >
    <stroke android:color="#ff5febe7" android:width="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="#601E3232"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```